# magento - sell products in groups

Tags: magento

I don't know what I should call this feature.

I have a catalog where I am going to sell Camera, Tv, Laptops, Memory Cards etc. and I have to  set my catalog like this where I can sell Camera, Memory Card as individual products, but I want to give a feature where a customer can purchase a Camera and a Memory Card together. Say a Select Box on Camera product description page which will contain the memory cards as options and the customer can Purchase one Memory Card with this Camera.  If customer does not select any option from this select box they will be charged with the price of the Camera.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could set them up as bundled products. When defining the bundle options you can select the way you wish to display them e.g. radio, drop down etc. This also gives you the ability to assign a fixed price to the bundle of products.

If you want to sell the camera at one price and the memory card at another price (i.e. they do not get a bundled price) I would recommend setting the memory Cards as related products.